# Google maps intent parameters

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-edittext

I want passing parameters taking from a edittext in the google maps.. the method:

```
public void nav() {
 String address = edit.getText().toString();
 address = address.replace(" ","+");
 String city = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+city));
 startActivity(i);
}
```

why `String city = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);`? Because the intent have to start only if in the edittext there is the word `bring`. So maps starts only if anyone write: `bring me New york` for example.. The "problem" is that actually the maps application takes the whole string and not only the city. I tried with the substring but not works.. Any way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are no spaces because you just replaced them all with "+" so if you want the user to write "bring me" (place name) than try this:

```
try {


String address = edit.getText().toString();
address = address.replace(" ","+");
address = address.substring(9);
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+address));
startActivity(i);

}

catch (Exception e){
}
```